# JPQL and timestamp with timezone

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have the following field definitions in one of my JPA entities:

```
@Column(nullable = false, name = "start_time",
columnDefinition= "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date startTime = new Date();

@Column(nullable = true, name = "end_time",
columnDefinition= "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date endTime = null;
```

The database is PostgreSQL and using timestamp without timezone is not an option. The inserts and updates are going fine regarding the timezone. A problem arises (at least I think so) when I try to run a SELECT JPQL query on some test data and the filter parameters are Date objects. The query OpenJPA generates doesn't include the timezone in the parameters.
Can anyone give me some guidance regarding JPA and timestamp with timezone columns?

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the use of Date and Calendar in JPA entities when they are being stored in the database.  **Standard** JDBC temporal values have no concept of timestamps.

I use the following style instead

```
private Long effectiveDate;
public Date getEffectiveDate() {
  if (effectiveDate == null) { return null; }
  return new Date(effectiveDate);
}
public void setEffectiveDate(Date d) {
  if (d == null) { effectiveDate = null; }
  effectiveDate = d.getTime();
}
```

Effectively the data that gets stored in the database is a simple long value.  However, on the application tier you still use the Date objects which have the concept of timezones.

Now sometimes you would still want to store the date for query purposes on the database level.  In which case you can do the following

```
private Long effectiveDate;
private Date effectiveDateDate;
public Date getEffectiveDate() {
  if (effectiveDate == null) { return null; }
  return new Date(effectiveDate);
}
public void setEffectiveDate(Date d) {
  effectiveDateDate = d;
  if (d == null) { effectiveDate = null; }
  effectiveDate = d.getTime();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You could have a look on java.util.Calendar.